# How to get the latest record in each group AND check if it's the only record?

Tags: mysql, sql

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1313293/1101095), the best way to get the latest record in each group is like this:

```
SELECT m1.*
FROM messages m1 
LEFT JOIN messages m2 ON (m1.name = m2.name AND m1.id < m2.id)
WHERE m2.id IS NULL
```

I have tried this and it works great.

However, I also need to check whether the latest record is the *only* record in the group. I tried modifying the query to this:

```
SELECT m1.*, COUNT(m3.name)
FROM messages m1 
LEFT JOIN messages m2 ON (m1.name = m2.name AND m1.id < m2.id)
LEFT JOIN messages m3 ON m1.name = m3.name
WHERE m2.id IS NULL
```

But it only returns one row.

If I remove the `COUNT()` statement, leaving us with this:

```
SELECT m1.*
FROM messages m1 
LEFT JOIN messages m2 ON (m1.name = m2.name AND m1.id < m2.id)
LEFT JOIN messages m3 ON m1.name = m3.name
WHERE m2.id IS NULL
```

Duplicate rows are returned, so apparently the additional `LEFT JOIN` messes up the query.

Is there a simple way to check whether the latest record returned is the *only* record in the group? A simple bool value would be fine, or the number of records in the group would work, too.

EDIT: The reason I'm trying to do this is that I'm writing a commenting system and I want users to be able to edit comments. When a comment is edited, I want to display a link showing it was edited that, when clicked, takes you to a page showing the edits (like on facebook, or how the revision system works for questions on stackoverflow). So I need to get the latest revision of each comment, as well as an indicator letting me know whether there are multiple revisions of the comment (so I know whether or not to show an "edited" link). The solution needs to be efficient, since there might be hundreds of comments in a thread.

Comment: That was the best way, once upon a time, but an uncorrelated subquery is likely to be much faster.

Comment: @Strawberry How would you go about doing that?

Comment: @Nate Just like the answers by Vulcronos and Gary

Comment: Yes, just like Vulcronos's answer - except I'd just write it using proper JOIN syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT m1.*, m2.total
FROM messages m1,
(select max(id) id, count(*) total, name
 from messages
 group by name) m2
where m1.name = m2.name and m1.id = m2.id
```

You can convert this to join syntax if you want, but the idea is to run a subquery and join once instead of twice and use only equality joins which could give you a performance boost.  I would benchmark both my solution and Aquillo's and see which is faster in your case.

Comment: How would you convert this to join syntax? I've been trying, but cannot for the life of me figure it out with the `max` in there :-)

Comment: Oh wow, lol, I just tried replacing the comma after m1 with JOIN and apparently that's all that had to be done! (I was trying to rewrite it in a clearly wrong manner). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not tested but I guess something like this would do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT m1.*
, CASE 
    WHEN m3.id IS NULL 
    THEN 'only record with this name' 
    ELSE 'not only record with this name' 
    END
FROM messages m1 
LEFT JOIN messages m2 ON (m1.name = m2.name AND m1.id < m2.id)
LEFT JOIN messages m3 ON (m1.name = m3.name AND m1.id > m3.id)
WHERE m2.id IS NULL
```

First `LEFT JOIN` + `WHERE` says "only give me the record with given name where there's no higher `id`".

Second `LEFT JOIN` says "give the records with given name and a smaller `id`". Since there might be more records, I've used this together with the `DISTINCT`. Last the `CASE WHEN THEN END` determines whether there was any smaller `id` at all.

Answer (score 1):

would something like this work for you

```
with cteMessages  as 

(select Name, max(Id) as LatestId, count(Id) as CountIds
from [Messages]
group by Name)

select * 
from  cteMessages as c
    inner join [Messages] as m 
        on c.Name = m.Name
        and c.LatestId = r.Id
```

Comment: oh, I just noticed that it is the same approach as @Vulcronos